# Session variables too persistent in OpenCart 1.5.3.1 (PHP)

Tags: php, opencart

I'm using a module called FB JS Connect (a free extension, and I can't seem to find it in Extensions now.) All it does is allow users to login using their Facebook ID.

It works pretty well, and uses FB API.

The problem is that, a user logs into OC using the FB Connect button, do something, then logs out. Another user logs in (not using FB Connect button), and the previous user's FB information is still in $_SESSION !

The 4 variables persist in $_SESSION are listed below, until new FB user logs in :

- fb__state
- fb__user_id
- fb__code
- fb__access_token

I don't dare to mess around in the code to "fix" this issue without expert advices because it might break a lot of things.

I guess I'll need to clear this manually.

I tried putting the following in index.php, and it seems that $session = new Session(); in index.php is called multiple times when user logs in.

```
// Session
$session = new Session();

unset($session->data['fb_<FBAppId>_state']);
unset($session->data['fb_<FBAppId>_code']);
unset($session->data['fb_<FBAppId>_user_id']);
unset($session->data['fb_<FBAppId>_access_token']);

$registry->set('session', $session);
```

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Place the above "unset" code into logout.php and this will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble with this specific extension as well and also cannot find it anymore in the OC extensions repo.  My suggestion is to use another extension: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3333

Comment: In fact, I think this other extension is by the same developer and may just be updated with bug fixes.

Comment: Hi Micah, the extension you mentioned has not been updated for a long time, and no questions have been answered by the dev. I'm sticking to FB JS Connect because it just works, and placing the "unset" code in logout.php fixes all issues.